# make ngOnChange fired when BehaviorSubject emit true value twice

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am working on an Angular 5 app. I have a dropdown component (  which has the following code in the html file,
***dropdown.component.html***

```
<p-dropdown [options]="data" [(ngModel)]="selectedFilterValue" placeholder="Please Select" [style]="{width: '100%'}" (onChange)="selectedValueChanged($event)"></p-dropdown>
```

***dropdown.component.tc***

```
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() ddOptions: string[] = [];
  @Input() filterName: string;
  @Input() clearDropDown: boolean = false;
```

I am using this dropdown component in my parent base where I am displaying 3 dropdowns, code looks as below,
***parent.component.html***

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-4">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
        <span class="col-xs-auto">PBG:</span>
        <arcm-dropdown class="col" [ddOptions]="pbgFilterValues" [clearDropDown]="clearDropdownObservable | async" (filterValue)="selectedValueChanged($event,FilterName.PBG)"></arcm-dropdown>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
        <span class="col-xs-auto">Wafer Size:</span>
        <arcm-dropdown class="col" [ddOptions]="waferSizeFilterValues" [clearDropDown]="clearDropdownObservable | async" (filterValue)="selectedValueChanged($event,FilterName.WaferSize)"></arcm-dropdown>
      </div>
    </div>
```

***parent.component.ts***

```
clearFilters(e:any):void{
     this.clearDropdownSubject.next(true);
  }
```

Now I have a button on the parent page called "clear filter" and on click of that button, I am emitting an value from my BehaviorSubject as true.  This value is being subscricbed by the child dropdown component.
**The problem is:**
First time when I emit value as "true", than child component ( dropdown component)  ngOnChanges get fired but when I emit the same value again , ngOnchang does not fired and I know why.  what should I do in this situation.

I thought of emitting random nummber instead of boolean but than random number can be same sometimes and that will make my  "clear filter" button not to function.

Comment: If you want a unique value you can emit`new Date().getTime()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently ran into the same issue. So, instead of pushing a primitive boolean to the `BehaviorSubject` stream, I used an object. For example, in your code, define an interface like this:

```
export interface Clear {
  clear: Boolean;
}
```

Then, change your parent component to this:

```
clearDropdownSubject$: BehaviorSubject<Clear> = new BehaviorSubject({ clear: false });

clearFilters(e: any): void {
  this.clearDropdownSubject.next({ clear: true });
}
```

Finally, in your DropdownComponent:

```
@Input() clearDropDown: Clear = { clear: false };
```

And update your code accordingly.

Comment: @Mikhail Kholodkov  Thanks. I like this approach of using object instead of a primitive type. Why I could not think of it man.

Answer (score 0):

This is how, I solved it for now, until get a better way,

```
clearFilters(e: any): void {

    let num: number = this.getRandomNumber();
    if (num > 0 && num != this.clearDropdownSubject.getValue()) {
      this.clearDropdownSubject.next(num);
      this.filterInputList = [];
    }
    else {
      this.clearFilters(0);
    }
  }


  getRandomNumber(): number {
    let randomNumber: number = 0;
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (100 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
  }
```